# RDOMail.SaveAs sometimes doesn't work over a UNC

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I have a C# Outlook add-in that is using the Redemption library.

This add-in, among other things, copy the selected mail to a share somewhere on the network.

It usually works pretty well but sometimes, the .msg file on the share seems to be corrupted. It cannot be read by the service that tries to process it. Double clicking on it shows this message: "*Cannot read the item*".

Sometimes, I can see an error message:

> SaveEmail - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007000):
>   Error in **StgCreateDocFile**: 0x8007000 at
>   **Redemption**.**IRDOMail**.**SaveAs**(String Path, Object Type) at
>   XYZNameSpace.Email.SaveEmail(...)

Here the code that save the mail to the share:

```
// Save the mail in a temp local file first
mailItem.SaveAs(temppath, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
(... some processing ...)
// Reload the mail
RDOMail rm = rdoSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(temppath);
// Save it again on a share
rm.SaveAs(filePathName, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

- Note 1 : I don't know why the mail is first saved locally!
- Note 2 : It is using an older version of Redemption (2015).
- Note 3 : The size of the message doesn't seem important. However, they are

usually between 2 and 15 MB.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IStorage API does not really like remote drives - there is no way for the storage sharing features to work.

Opening and saving the message the second time really does not make much sense - why not simply copy the MSG file using the file system API?

Comment: I will most certainly rewrite this part and replace the save on the remote drive by a simple file copy. Can you explain what you mean by "there is no way for the storage sharing features to work"? Thank a lot Dmitry.

Comment: COM system allows to share IStorage files between different processes. But it only works for the local drives.